# Vimeo API v3: request to get multiple videos by Video Id's

Tags: vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Is there any way, where we can make an API request for multiple video details by using a list of ID's ? Just like how Youtube provides googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=[ID1,ID2,ID3]. Can we achieve the same through Vimeo ? Guide through pls. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. It's planned though!

Your best solution might be to add them in a channel, group or album, then query for that collections videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a comma-separated list of video URIs to get the details of multiple videos in one go.
Like this,

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos?uris=/videos/111,/videos/222,/videos/333
```

Here is the Vimeo documentation for the same: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#search_videos